# Working with some members of a struct affects other members of the struct C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

---

QUESTION ANSWERED , THANK YOU
The problem apparently came from not declaring the vf large enough to also contain 9 --> It should be vf[10]

---

Long story short , in the input file I have a 2d array of 9 x 9 elements. It holds elements from {0 , 1 ... 9}. I need to figure out exactly how many times each number appears on each line ( for this I used the **vf[]** array ) , and how many are different from 0 ( for this I used '**number**' ). I included **vf[]** and **number** into a struct , as following :

```
struct Line
{
    short vf[9];
    short number;
}L[10];
```

After reading the 2d array , I used **Analyze()** to determine for each line how many numbers are different from 0 and how many times each number appears on that line.

```
void Analyze()
{
    for ( short i = 1 ; i <= 9 ; ++i )        // lines
        for ( short j = 1 ; j <= 9 ; ++j )    //columns
            if ( M[i][j] )                    //different from 0
            {
                L[i].number++;
                L[i].vf[ M[i][j] ]++;
            }
}
```

Now , here appears a problem that I just can not explain. This is how the input looks:

```
2 5 8 7 3 0 9 4 1    // number should be 8
6 0 9 8 2 4 3 0 7    // number should be 7
4 0 7 0 1 5 2 6 0    // number should be 6
3 9 5 2 7 0 4 0 6    // number should be 7
0 6 2 4 0 8 1 0 5    // number should be 6
8 4 0 6 5 0 7 2 9    // number should be 7
1 8 4 3 6 9 5 7 2    // number should be 9
0 7 0 1 4 2 0 9 3    // number should be 6
9 2 3 5 8 7 6 1 4    // number should be 9
```

However , the numbers I get from each line are :

```
9 8 6 8 6 8 10 7 10
```

Now , if I remove the *L[i].vf[ M[i][j] ]++;* line from **Analyze()** , I get a different output , which is:

```
8 7 6 7 6 7 9 6 9
```

So the question is , does anyone have a hunch of why increasing **vf[]** also seems to have an effect on **number** ?

Go easy on me if I made any english mistakes please.

Comment: How is M declared? Is it M[10][10]?  How about the contents of M - is the range 0..8?

Comment: I don't think it should be a problem if I also read the array in this way. This is how I was taught in school and it became a habit . Yes it is declared short M[10][10] . It can only contain elements from { 0 ... 9 } .

Comment: There is no `vf[9]`, indices of `vf` range from 0 to 8.

Comment: It's probably undefined behaviour because the mere sight of something like `i <= 9` in a loop condition suggests that you are reading one-past-the-end of something. But you must post an MCVE, or else it's just guessing.

Comment: It really wasn't the fact that I went with i from 1 to 9 because I also read the array in this way. n.m. is correct ,after increasing vf[] to vf[10] the problem seems to go away. Thank you!!

Comment: Please don't use arrays like this in C or C++ (you shouldn't be using C style arrays in C++ at all). If you need a 9×9 matrix, declare it as `M[9][9]` and run loops `for i = 0; i < 9; ++i)`.

Comment: It is accetable to write an answer to your own question and accept it. Please consider doing so. Adding "thank you, solved" notes to the question itself is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some mistakes/changes I have shown/made to this code:

```
struct Line
{
    short vf[9]; 
             ^^ here a number 9 can't be counted as index range is 0-8
    short number;
    Line()
    {
        std::fill_n(v,9,0); //fills the array with 0
        number = 0; // Initialized the number with 0
    }

}L[10];
```

> Edit: Thanks to  `@HolyBlackCat`'s comment  I realized  mistake in the initialization part. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Is it necessary to declare them to 0 if it is above main? I never had problems with global undeclared variables.

Comment: `vf[9] = {0};` doesn't initialize anything. It assigns `0` to non-existing array element, resulting in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for pointing this out. Changed the answer.

Comment: @MihaiBontea Initializing arrays are good practices in C++. You can check many answers regarding this topic like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040355/is-it-good-practice-to-initialize-array-in-c-c).